LWC slds table onblur function
not able to call onblur function in LWC js
In my LWC slds table I've used this in td key={field} data-field={field.fieldValue} data-index={indexRow} data-column={colIndex}  onblur={onblurData} class="Refresh Graph" onclick={handleEditUnit}>{field.fieldValue} and when user click on this then input box will be shown of this:-  when user click on the table then an input box will open and eg=hen user do any changes in that and when user click out of the input box then the onblur function will called but if user click on the data in td and don't make any changes and click outside of the output box then the onblur function is not calling. Is there any suggestions for this?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
